# testng - creating KnownFault and IntermittentFailure annotations

Tags: java, testng

I would like to annotate some of my test cases with KnownFault - which would do pretty much what expectedException does plus some magic using YouTrack's REST API. I would also like to have an IntermittentFailure attribute which would mean that I'm aware that the test might occasionally fail with [exception] [message] but I wouldn't want this to block the rest of my build chain.

After some research I found that my test class should implement IHookable, then I could have something like this:

```
@Override
public void run(IHookCallBack callBack, ITestResult result) {
    callBack.runTestMethod(result);
    if (result.getThrowable().getCause() instanceof IllegalArgumentException){
        System.out.println("This is expected.");
        result.setThrowable(null);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Unexpected exception");
    }
}
```

The problem with this is the actual implementation of invokeHookable:

```
final Throwable[] error = new Throwable[1];

IHookCallBack callback = new IHookCallBack() {
  @Override
  public void runTestMethod(ITestResult tr) {
    try {
      invokeMethod(thisMethod, testInstance, parameters);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      error[0] = t;
      tr.setThrowable(t); // make Throwable available to IHookable
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Object[] getParameters() {
    return parameters;
  }
};
hookable.run(callback, testResult);
if (error[0] != null) {
  throw error[0];
}
```

Unfortunately that last line means that my test case is going to throw an exception no matter what as the `error` array is completely out of my hands in the `run` method.

So, what would be the proper way of intercepting an exception and handling it the way I want to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is really interesting. You should try to propose changes on https://github.com/cbeust/testng/pull/

But maybe `IHookable` is not the best listener you can use. Did you try [`IInvokedMethodListener`](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IInvokedMethodListener.html)?

```
void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult result) {
    if (result.getThrowable().getCause() instanceof IllegalArgumentException) {
        System.out.println("This is expected.");
        result.setThrowable(null);
        result.setStatus(SUCCESS); // If you want to change the status
    } else {
        System.out.println("Unexpected exception");
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, that worked. So the base class has to be slightly modified in case of using a Listener: I added a class called `TestListener` that does your proposed implementation, then I have to annotate the tests' base class with `@Listeners(TestListener.class)`. Worked like a charm!

Comment: Or you can use any other listener detection mechanism if you prefer http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners